# How can you have one property of an object listed in a dropdown and still access all properties later?

Tags: javascript, forms, javascript-objects

I am new to javascript and would appreciate some input from some of you wise, veteran javascripters.

Context: I am filling a dropdown selection form (id: foodList, located within the html page) with an array of objects with several properties. I want the dropdown menu to show one property (in this case, foodName) of the object for each option, but for the rest of the object properties to remain accessible. At the moment, the dropdown lists the options by foodName, but brings up the error that it "cannot read property 'foodName' of undefined."

```
function Food (foodName, servingSize, calsPerServing, price) {
    this.foodName = foodName;
    this.servingSize = servingSize;
    this.calsPerServing = calsPerServing;
    this.price = price;
}

var ramenChicken = new Food("Ramen, Chicken Flavor", "1 package", 380, 0.17);
var ramenBeef = new Food("Ramen, Beef Flavor", "1 package", 380, 0.17);
var ramenOriental = new Food("Ramen, Oriental Flavor", "1 package", 380, 0.17);

var pantry = popFoodList(ramenChicken, ramenOriental, ramenBeef);

function popFoodList(list) {
    var select = document.getElementById("foodList");
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var opt = arguments[i].foodName;
        var optFull = arguments[i];
        var el = document.createElement('option');
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = optFull;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    popFoodList(pantry);
});
```

Comment: I would think `el.value = opt;` would set the value to what you want. I would also set `el.optFull = optFull;` Then when you reference it later make sure you're using that same path `el.optFull.servingSize` for example. Also make sure when you're referencing it, you're referencing the DOMElement not the jQuery collection (since I see you using JQ). Some jQuery callbacks receive their parameters as a jQuery collection containing the DOMElement(s)

Comment: I've transferred that comment into an answer in case anyone else comes along with this issue and comes across this question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off. To make this work, you need to store the object attached to the DOMElement and address it at the same location when you later reference it again.

So changing your code to:

```
function popFoodList(list) {
    var select = document.getElementById("foodList");
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var opt = arguments[i].foodName;
        var optFull = arguments[i];
        var el = document.createElement('option');
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        el.optFull = optFull; //this assigns the object to the DOMElement
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
};
```

That will allow you later to reference the entire object like so:

```
el.optFull.servingSize
```

Also make sure when you're referencing it, you're referencing the DOMElement not the jQuery collection (since I see you using JQ). Some jQuery callbacks receive their parameters as a jQuery collection containing the DOMElement(s)